# onreadystatechange not submit forms or it always submits forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I want my input email address to be checked on registration page.  I am right now using *onreadystatechange* to get the response from database with *responseText*. If *responseText* is true, then do not submit the form, otherwise, submit.
However, my code will always submit my forms even if the condition is true.

//////////////HTML file//////////////////

```
<form action="regist.php" method="post" id="submitForm">
  <label>*Email:</label>
  <label class="validate" id="emailError">XXXX@XXXX.XXX</label></br>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email"/></br>
  <label>*First Name:</label>
  <label class="validate" id="firstnameError">Letters only!</label>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"/></br>
  <label>Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"/></br>
  <label>*Password:</label>
  <label class="validate" id="passwordError">at least 6 characters!</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/></br>
  <label class="validate" id="used">Email has been used!</label></br>
  <button id="Validate">Register</button>
</form>
```

////////////////////JS file////////////////

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#regi").click(function () {
    var popup = $("#register").dialog({modal: true});
    popup.show();
  });
  $("#Validate").click(function () {
    validate();
  });
});

function validate() {
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var error = $("#used");
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "backend.php?req=checkDuplicate&user=" + email, true);
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      if (xmlhttp.responseText == 1) {//check if email existed in db, return 1
        error.show();
        console.log("find match! Do not proceed!!");
        $('#submitForm').submit(false);
      }
      else {
        error.hide();
        console.log("Redirect");
        $('#submitForm').submit(true);//only here should do redirect
      }
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: It seems that you already use jQuery, so why you don't use jQuery ajax method ?

Comment: Thanks. I will try it later

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should read some documentation about [jQuery submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

```js
function validate() {
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var error = $("#used");
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "backend.php?req=checkDuplicate&user=" + email, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
  if (xmlhttp.responseText == 1) {//check if email existed in db, return 1
    error.show();
    console.log("find match! Do not proceed!!");

    // if you don't want to proceed just don't call submit !
    // $('#submitForm').submit(false);
  }
  else {
    error.hide();
    console.log("Redirect");
    //$('#submitForm').submit(true);//only here should do redirect
    // remove the true value using jQuery to trigger the submit
      $('#submitForm').submit();
  }
 }
}
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Using [jQuery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) you can have same result with that :

```js
  function validate() {

    var email = $("#email").val();
    var error = $("#used");
    var url = "backend.php?req=checkDuplicate&user=" + email; 

      $.get(url , function( data ){

        if(data===1){

          error.show();
          console.log("find match! Do not proceed!!");

        }else{

          error.hide();
          console.log("Redirect");
          $('#submitForm').submit()

        }

      });
  }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the way you recommend but still has the problem. Then, I delete  the form tags in html _<form action="regist.php" method="post" id="submitForm">_ and _.submit()_ method in js. Instead, I used _xmlhttp.open("GET", "backend.php?req=checkDuplicate&user="+email+"&last="+lastname+"&first="+firstname+"&pass="+password, true);_ to pass the value as a workaround. Now everything is fine.